# sed replace using wildcard

Tags: unix, sed

How can I carry out the replace below with sed?

input

```
group_0 group_10 n_name_0 n_name_10 n_name_20 n_name_5 n_name_40 team_20 team_1
```

required output

```
group_0 group_10 n_name n_name n_name n_name n_name n_name team_20 team_1
```

I tried using sed -i 's/n_name*/n_name/g' but it deletes everything after n_name

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i 's:\(n_name\)_[[:digit:]]*:\1:g'
```

Comment: I gave you a detailed answer. Does it help you ?

Comment: group_0 group_10      team_20 team_1. I am seeing this output. The string gets replaced by a character which looks something like []

Answer (score 0):

works based on your input data:

```
sed -r 's/_[0-9]+//g'
```

see the line below:

```
kent$   echo "group0 group1 n_name_0 n_name_10 n_name_20 n_name_5 n_name_40 team0 team1"|sed -r 's/_[0-9]+//g'
group0 group1 n_name n_name n_name n_name n_name team0 team1
```

**update**

updated for your new input

```
sed -r 's/(n_name)_[0-9]+/\1/g'
```

test:

```
kent$ echo "group_0 group_10 n_name_0 n_name_10 n_name_20 n_name_5 n_name_40 team_20 team_1"|sed -r 's/(n_name)_[0-9]+/\1/g' 
group_0 group_10 n_name n_name n_name n_name n_name team_20 team_1
```

**update**

i assume that you want to use that line in your shell script. so see the test below:

```
kent$  ls
test.txt

kent$  cat test.txt 
group_0 group_10 n_name_0 n_name_10 n_name_20 n_name_5 n_name_40 team_20 team_1

kent$  commandSed=$(sed -r 's/(n_name)_[0-9]+/\1/g' test.txt > out.txt)

kent$  ls
out.txt  test.txt

kent$  cat out.txt
group_0 group_10 n_name n_name n_name n_name n_name team_20 team_1
```

in fact the commandSed var doesn't make any sense here.

if you do:

```
kent$  commandSed=$(sed -r 's/(n_name)_[0-9]+/\1/g' test.txt)
```

(without redirecting to new file)

```
kent$  echo $commandSed 
group_0 group_10 n_name n_name n_name n_name n_name team_20 team_1
```

if you want to have the output **both** in new file and commandSed variable, tee is your friend:

```
kent$  commandSed=$(sed -r 's/(n_name)_[0-9]+/\1/g' test.txt|tee out.txt)  

kent$  echo $commandSed                                                  
group_0 group_10 n_name n_name n_name n_name n_name team_20 team_1

kent$  cat out.txt 
group_0 group_10 n_name n_name n_name n_name n_name team_20 team_1
```

Comment: group_0 group_10      team_20 team_1. This the output I am getting with your script, seem to delete n_name. I am running $commandSed ="sed -r 's/(n_name)_[0-9]+/\1/g' " . $userPath . "test.txt>out.txt";  
system($commandSed);

Comment: @SantoshPillai could you pls copy and try that line in my answer, echo ...|sed.. what output it gives u?

Comment: How to I use this to modify my file. $commandSed =exec("sed -r 's/(n_name)_[0-9]+/\1/g' test.txt>new.txt");  too deletes  n_name

Comment: would you know the php syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was quite simple. Found this on http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/31583-wildcards-sed.html

```
$commandSed ="sed -r 's/n_name_[0-9]*/un_cell/g' test.txt>out.txt";
system($commandSed);
```